# Can someone please explain what does $ D= P^{-1} AP$ mean in simple terms?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I know how determine whether or not a matrix is diagonalizable, but after that the question will usually ask me to find an invertible matrix P and a diagonal matrix D such that $$ D= P^{-1} AP$$.

I was hoping someone would be able to explain what this means, why it's important, and maybe a very simple example.

Comment: What is the definition of a diagonalizable matrix?

Comment: I prefer to think of it as $A = P D P^{-1}$. The matrix $P^{-1}$ changes basis from the standard basis to the basis consisting of the columns of $P$. Then we multiply by the diagonal matrix $D$ (easy). Then we multiply by $P$ to change back to the standard basis. This is equivalent to just multiplying by $A$. The point is that once we have switched to the new basis, we only have to multiply by a diagonal matrix (easy) instead of multiplying by $A$ (difficult).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A linear transformation is diagonal if there is some basis where the matrix representation of that transformation is a diagonal matrix. A matrix is diagonalizable if it represents a diagonal linear transformation.

So $P$ is a change-of-basis matrix that takes us from the basis that $A$ is described in (say the standard basis) to whatever basis makes the linear transformation instead represented by the diagonal matrix $D$. The columns of $P$ will be eigenvectors of $A$ (described in the standard basis), and the entries of $D$ will be the corresponding eigenvalues in the same order.

Really, I'm more used to seeing $$A=PDP^{-1}$$ than the other way around. The most immediate use of this is how much easier it is to calculate high powers of the right-hand side than of the left-hand side: you just calculate the corresponding powers of the diagonal elements.

As an example, consider $$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$$(Symmetric matrices are always nice and diagonalizable, so it's a good place to look for examples.) Doing the rote calculations, we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}3&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac12&\frac12\\\frac12&-\frac12\end{bmatrix}
$$
as, for instance, $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $3$, so it's the first column of $P$ and the first entry of $D$.

Now consider trying to calculate $A^{500}$. Not a task I would at all enjoy doing by hand. But using the powers of diagonalization, we get
$$
A^{500}=\left(PDP^{-1}\right)^{500}\\
=PD^{500}P^{-1}
$$
And calculating $D^{500}$ is comparatively easy, assuming you know your powers of $3$.

Comment: I think I understand it all now. I don't think I originally understood the significance of eigenvalues/eigenvectors. Is the whole point of calculating them is so that you can diagonalize a matrix?

Comment: @PaulSilvestri There are other uses of eigenvectors too, and in particular there are matrices that have eigenvectors but cannot be diagonalized. But diagonalization is, depending on how you look at it, either a very good application of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, or simply a way to record them that eases arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to know that linear transformations correspond to matrices, that this correspondence depends on choosing a basis and that replacing one basis by another replaces a matrix $A$ by a matrix $P^{-1}AP$ where $P$ expresses one basis in terms of the other but it is also good to know that the entire discussion can be framed in purely matrix terms without mentioning bases. Given a matrix $A$ there are many reasons for trying to find an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=D$ where $D$ is diagonal. One important application is to find powers of $A$, which is very useful, even if you don't care at all about bases or linear transformations but there are many other applications. For example, suppose you have a system of differential equations 
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1'\\.\\.\\.\\x_n'\end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\.\\.\\.\\x_n\end{bmatrix}$$ and you have an invertible matrix $P.$ Then if you define new variables $u_1,...,u_n$ by $$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\.\\.\\.\\x_n\end{bmatrix}=P\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\.\\.\\.\\u_n\end{bmatrix}$$ it follows that $$\begin{bmatrix}u_1'\\.\\.\\.\\u_n'\end{bmatrix}=P^{-1}AP\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\.\\.\\.\\u_n\end{bmatrix}.$$ If $P^{-1}AP=D$ where $D$ is diagonal, say with diagonal elements $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$, then it is very easy to solve the differential equations for $u_1,...,u_n.$ In fact, the solution is $$u_1=c_1e^{\lambda_1t},...,u_n=c_ne^{\lambda_nt}.$$Once the $u_i$ are known, it follows that $$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\.\\.\\.\\x_n\end{bmatrix}=P\begin{bmatrix}c_1e^{\lambda_1t}\\.\\.\\.\\c_ne^{\lambda_nt}\end{bmatrix}$$. One last remark: I am a bit puzzled by your statement that you know how to determine  whether $A$ is diagonalizable but apparently regard finding $P$ and $D$ as a separate question. The way that I answer these questions is to do them together. First, given an $n \times n$ real matrix, I try to solve the equation  $\det(\lambda I-A)=0.$ If the roots are not all real, then we know immediately that $A$ is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb R.$ Suppose all the roots $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m$ are real amd that the algebraic multiplcity of $\lambda_i$ in the characteristic equation $\det(\lambda I-A)=0$ is $\mu_i, 1 \le i \le m.$ Then for each $i$, I check whether or not there are $\mu_i$ linearly independent column-vectors $\mathbf v$ such that $(\lambda_i I-A)\mathbf v=0.$[Yes, I know that we have found a basis for the eigenspace and that I said we were not ging to talk about bases. I have put a little water in my wine.] If there is any $i$ for which this condition is not satisfied, the matrix $A$ is not diagonalizable. If this condition is satisfied for all $i$, then we set $D$ to be the diagonal matrix in which $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m$ are the diagonal elements with each $\lambda_i$ repeated $\mu_i$ times. The matrix $P$ is formed by writing down side by side all the linearly independent column vectors $\mathbf v$ that we found for all the $\lambda_i.$